# Kylin Web UI and HBase Web UI on Docker does not work properly (Ubuntu 18)

Tags: docker, kylin

I installed kylin on docker with this command `docker pull apachekylin/apache-kylin-standalone:3.0.0-alpha2` and it was fine.

And then I ran

```
docker run -d \
 -m 8G \
 -p 7070:7070 \
 -p 8088:8088 \
 -p 50070:50070 \
 -p 8032:8032 \
 -p 8042:8042 \
 -p 60010:60010 \
 apachekylin/apache-kylin-standalone:3.0.0-alpha2
```

But when I try to reach `http://127.0.0.1:7070/` or `http://127.0.0.1:60010/` it does not open. `http://127.0.0.1:50070/` and `127.0.0.1:8088` are working properly.

OS: Ubuntu 18.

**How can i fix this?**

Comment: Do you get any log messages?

Comment: Hello Scorpioo590, i get a log message saying 'port 7070' is in use.

Comment: This means that some other service on your machine is blocking that port so your docker container can not use it.
Try running the docker command with a different port (e.g. `-p7071:7070`)

Comment: OK! Its show this WARNING: Your kernel does not support swap limit capabilities or the cgroup is not mounted. Memory limited without swap.
4dbe1866959968043be72456d1e4ba1c11af34a81110e31adade5272ea0b66c6

Comment: That's just a warning

Answer (score 1):

i change the docker memory to 8G later it works. maybe you can try it.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? The OP already has `-m 8G`. Or do you mean something else?